# Android Studio; Jetpack Compose : Preview could not be rendered due to errors when using rememberPermissionState

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I tackled this problem when trying to request for permissions using the Accompanist library.

Here is a snippet of code causing the problem, the function is Composable and is also opted for experimental API.

```
if (City.value == "") {
        /* val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) */
        Button(
            onClick = {
                //getPermissions(permissionState)
                pickLauncher.launch("application/vnd.ms-excel")
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(10.dp),
        ) {
            Text("Select City")
        }
    }
```

Whenever I uncomment the lines that implement the rememberPermissionState, the preview errors out (although the build is successful) and also gives nothing in the Compose errors tab.

Why is this happening? For now I am simply developing with this commented out.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs because `rememberPermissionState()` requires an Activity that is not available in the Preview mode.

You can use a custom workaround:

```
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Composable
fun rememberPermissionStateSafe(permission: String, onPermissionResult: (Boolean) -> Unit = {}) = when {
    LocalInspectionMode.current -> remember {
        object : PermissionState {
            override val permission = permission
            override val status = PermissionStatus.Granted
            override fun launchPermissionRequest() = Unit
        }
    }
    else -> rememberPermissionState(permission, onPermissionResult)
}
```

By using the `rememberPermissionStateSafe()` method instead of `rememberPermissionState()` you will obtain the granted state of your permission in the Preview mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the compose render problems, you will notice following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permissions should be called in the context of an Activity
   at com.google.accompanist.permissions.PermissionsUtilKt.findActivity(PermissionsUtil.kt:138)
   at com.google.accompanist.permissions.MutablePermissionStateKt.rememberMutablePermissionState(MutablePermissionState.kt:51)
   at com.google.accompanist.permissions.PermissionStateKt.rememberPermissionState(PermissionState.kt:38)
```

As a workaround, you can implement `PermissionState` just for preview:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
class PreviewPermissionState(
    private val _permission: String = Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    private val _status: PermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.Granted
) : PermissionState {
    override val permission: String
        get() = _permission
    override val status: PermissionStatus
        get() = _status

    override fun launchPermissionRequest() {
    }
}
```

Then you will have to hoist `rememberPermissionState`:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
fun SettingsScreen(
    permissionState: @Composable (onPermissionResult: (Boolean) -> Unit) -> PermissionState,
) {
    val permissionState = permissionState {
        ..

        if (it) {
            activityResultLauncher.launch()
        }
    }
    ..
}

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
fun SettingsScreen() {
    SettingsScreen(permissionState = { onPermissionResult ->
        rememberPermissionState(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) {
            onPermissionResult(
                it
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Now you can use `PreviewPermissionState` to preview `SettingsScreen`:

```
@Preview
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
fun SettingsScreenPreview() {
    SettingsScreen { PreviewPermissionState() }
}
```

This will now allow compose to render preview correctly. Make sure to check the rendered problems for other issues.